# How can I display just a part of a Webpage? UIWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am working on my `iOS`-App in Swift and I've already finished my Android-App. On Android, I already found a solution to display **just a part** of a webpage. This is what I want to do to my iOS-app, too.

So, for those who are familiar with android developing, it was this solution which helped me:

[How to display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477584/how-to-display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android)

**But I asked my question in a way that it is possible to answer this question even if you don't have experience with android developing!**

You can assume that, as this android solution does, my webpage is darebee.com, in this case maybe on the workout-page, so I precisely mean:

https://darebee.com/wods.html

I want to show **just one `div` class** which shows the content of the page, in this case:

```
<div class="ja-products-wrapper products wrapper grid products-grid cols-3">
```

That is my code until now (working, but showing full page):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL (string: "https://darebee.com/wods.html")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```

I know there is also a way to hide some parts of the webpage, but it would be far more easier, elegant and shorter to just show this one `div`-class.

Is it possible to do this? It would be nice to get an answer which is helpful.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution that might be helpful for me, but somehow it is not working.
Because the code was 2,5 years old, something I deprecated so I had to update the code to my own.
Maybe on the constraints part, there could be a mistake, but there are no errors at all. Also the backgroundColor is not visible although all the lines I wanted to print are printed. 
Maybe you can look to my code and, if it helps you, compare it to the solution I found: [How to only display part of web page content (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581935/how-to-only-display-part-of-web-page-content-swift)

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private weak var webView: WKWebView!


@IBOutlet weak var vclabel: UIView!

private var userContentController: WKUserContentController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createViews()
    print("no prob1")
    loadPage(urlString: "https://dribbble.com/", partialContentQuerySelector: ".dribbbles.group")
    print("no prob2")
}

private func createViews() {
    userContentController = WKUserContentController()

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userContentController

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let color1 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
    webView.backgroundColor = color1
    if (webView.backgroundColor == color1){
        print("color1")
    }
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: vclabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addSubview(webView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, topConstraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    self.webView = webView
}

private func loadPage(urlString: String, partialContentQuerySelector selector: String) {
    userContentController.removeAllUserScripts()
    print("load")
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: scriptWithDOMSelector(selector: selector),
                                  injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
                                  forMainFrameOnly: true)

    userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
    print("loaded")
}

private func scriptWithDOMSelector(selector: String) -> String {
    print("DOMSelector")
    let script =
        "var selectedElement = document.querySelector('\(selector)');" +
    "document.body.innerHTML = selectedElement.innerHTML;"
    return script
}

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}

}
```

And this is my output:

```
Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
color1
no prob1
load
DOMSelector
loaded
no prob2
```

I just don't know what else I should do to get an answer to this question. 
Anyone out there who can help me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Use LoadHtmlString like this:

```
 let requestURL: URL? = yourWebView.request().url
 var error: Error?
 let page = try? String(contentsOf: requestURL, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
 yourWebView.loadHTMLString(page!, baseURL: requestURL)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to my question. Maybe you could look on my question a second time and then think about your solution

Comment: that would be nice!

Comment: what's up? Can you help me or is this not possible for you? I edited my question so that it is more clearly what the question is about.